# Use multiple crash reporter on iOS

Tags: ios, service, crash-reports, testflight

We successfully use [TestFlightLive](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/live/) as our crash reporter, but I think some features are missing. These missing features are in another crash reporter: [Crashlytics](http://www.crashlytics.com), but as of now I'm not willig to switch crash reporters completely. So I wonder if it's possible to use these both crash reporters together in one app (which is meant to be in the app store in the future).

Comment: check this out. : http://www.grahamdennis.me/blog/2012/10/21/how-to-disable-testflights-crash-handlers/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I run both TestFlight and Crashlytics together and they both report errors fine. Like [Jens Kohl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/408150/jens-kohl) says above, it must be included after the TestFlight SDK is initialized. Here's my code:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    // setup testflight if in debug (ie dev) mode
    [TestFlight takeOff:kTestFlightAPIKey];
#endif

    [Crashlytics startWithAPIKey:kCrashlyticsAPIKey];
```

Comment: Note: This works with these two in combination. It will not work with any combination of multiple 3rd party crash reporters. We have seen multiple cases where some crash reports do not forward the catched exceptions or other crashes to another instance and hence the other report will not report anything or anything helpful.

Comment: Wait a sec. Because TestFlight is in the DEBUG #ifdef, you are only using Crashlytics in production, no?

Comment: Yup, this was back before TestFlight was meant to run in production. If you want to run TestFlight all the time just unwrap it from the ifdef.

Answer (score 4):

You can only use 1 crash reporting framework. The framework catching the crash lets the other framework either not catch it or get wrong data since there is already new code executed on the thread.

Comment: The Crashlytics support replied that they just need to be the last called crash reporting toolkit and they haven't any issues until now when using another crash reporter alongside Crashlytics. I'll give it  a try, but thanks nevertheless.

Comment: Their crash reporter is basically PLCrashReporter with most classes renamed. And PLCrashReporter let's the app crash once all data is collected. So that is one reason it has to be last. But depending on what kind of crash reporters run before it, the run Objective-C code themselves, which is not only unsafe ( http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/objc/Reliable_Crash_Reporting.20110912.html ), but also alters the call stacks on the crashing threads. So it may work, but it is not safe to say it works in general. Results of both reports can be very different an inaccurate.